# Java FX - Dividing a Node for multiple page printout

Tags: javafx, printing

I been searching for post about multiple page printout on javafx. they say that for a node that is too big to fit on one page must be divided and pass each for printjob. the instruction given for that is too vague for me to understand.

Let say i have a TextArea with a list of hundreds of names which obviously would not fit in one page. How will i divide that into a multiple of nodes to pass each on the print method of PrintJob? (output to be printed on a letter size paper)

Comment: `TextArea` is not a good example since it may not display the content completely. Displaying all text for differnet scroll positions of the `TextArea` is a completely different issue from printing parts of a scene has a great height...

Comment: what node can you suggest best suited for this type of problem. what if it is a text editor application printing multiple paragraph file. can you provide a code printing different scroll position?

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit that I have never done that myself but what I would try is the following: Assume you have a node which would cover two pages when printed as a whole. I would then set a clipping rectange on the top level node which covers the left page and then print it. After that I would set a new clipping rectangle wich covers the second page and transform the node so that the second page starts in the uppder left corner and then again print it. I think this could work but as I said before I have never done that before.

Comment: i've never done that clipping rectangle that would cover the entire page size that i want.(or rather i do not know how to do that algorithm :D) can you please add a simple snippet of code that would print the clipped part of the node and the transform part.